# Referencing the Name of a Button assigned through a method

Tags: java, swing, calculator

Just as a hint of back story, I am really getting into java and have been watching all these videos and such online, I decided that while learning it is good, if I can't make practical use of it, its pointless. So I went with a calculator. All is going good except one thing.

To just showcase my laziness I made a method that accepts parameters and uses them to build a JButton with a simple method call. That code is:

```
public class GUI_Element_Methods{

private JButton button1;
private JButton numpad[];


public void createButton(String buttonText, ActionListener eventMethod, boolean visible, String tooltipText){

    button1 = new JButton(buttonText);
    button1.addActionListener(eventMethod);
    button1.setVisible(visible);
    button1.setToolTipText(tooltipText);

}

public JButton getButton1(){
    return(button1);
}
```

Called Upon:

```
guiElement.createButton("+", asHandler, true, "Addition");
    add(guiElement.getButton1());
```

I works all well and good, but I am having trouble trying to detect if a action was a certain button in the event handler since they all run though this "button1" JButton. For example, The pythagorean theorem, it has two variants based off what you are trying to solve for and I would like to use just 1 event handler to just detect which one is pressed.

```
if(event.getSource().equals()){
}else{
}
```

That was how I assumed I would put it, I just don't know how to reference the method created buttons.

Comment: You might also like to return the button from the `createButton` method, it might make it easier on the caller

Answer (score 5):

You could always try to distinguish the button pressed by getting its actionCommand, i.e,

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
}
```

You can then compare that String with String constants to see if you have the button you desire.

---

For example:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;   
import javax.swing.*;

public class NumberPad extends JPanel {
   public static final String[][] NUMBER_TEXTS = {
      {"7", "8", "9"},
      {"4", "5", "6"},
      {"1", "2", "3"}
   };

   public NumberPad() {
      ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("ActionCommand: " + e.getActionCommand());
         }
      };
      setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3));
      for (String[] row : NUMBER_TEXTS) {
         for (String cell : row) {
            JButton button = new JButton(cell);
            button.addActionListener(actionListener);
            add(button);
         }
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      NumberPad mainPanel = new NumberPad();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Number Pad");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, get action command worked. Looking at your code reminded me of the existence of multidimensional arrays, completely forgot about those. I should use one of the number pad.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `ArrayList` which will contain all the `JButton` objects you will create.

Add the buttons to it and compare them on your `actionPerformed` method.

```
List<JButton> btnList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
. . .
btnList.add(button1);
. . .
void actionPerformed(...)
for(JButton btn : btnList){
if(event.getSource().equals(btn)){
//do whatever you want with this button.
}
}
```

Comment: 1) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.